# Code for how to prevent user from refreshing the page either by using refresh button of browser or CTRL+F5 in angular js

Tags: angularjs

Code for how to  prevent user from refreshing the page either by using refresh button of browser or CTRL+F5 in angular js

Comment: You can't. Why do you want to prevent it?

Comment: Because that page is holding form data and user may accidentally refresh the page

Comment: save it in a `localstorage`

Comment: Are you asking how to make the "please confirm you want to leave the page" dialogå like the one you get when you try to refresh when writing an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Well you cannot stop the user form manually refreshing the page, and not a good UX as well. Instead you can ask for confirmation for page reload. In JS we handle this using **window.onbeforeunload**:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Your form progress will be lost, are you sure you want to reload this page?";
}
```

[This reference shows you how to achieve this in Angular Js](https://gist.github.com/981746/3b6050052ffafef0b4df)

Comment: Note that newer browsers [don't support a custom onBeforeUnload message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own).